# Bigcommerce API Programmer For Custom Fields

Tags: api, bigcommerce

We are wanting to add custom product attributes to a BigCommerce store using API so that the main global product page will have the custom product attributes for cigars in our case.

Below are the product attributes so you get an idea on what it will include. We need the ability to have these attribute fields in the admin so when we add or import products they will be populated manually or automatically on the import.

County, Wrapper, Binder, Package, Size, Strength, Shape.

An example of those customs fields you can see on this other website.

http://www.thecigarstore.com/Cigars/Rocky-Patel/Rocky-Patel-Sun-Grown-Toro.htm

This is BigCommerce's API page on this.
http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/products/custom_fields

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405477/how-can-i-update-custom-fields-using-the-bigcommerce-api/16468161#16468161), this seems to be a bug in the API. I am not sure what are Bigcommerce plans to fix it, but I imagine there's plenty of people waiting to be fixed.