# How to update Custom Customer Fields using API in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have couple of custom fields that I have created under Account Sign up, how do I update these fields using API?

When I try to pull the customer data, I get as an array for "form_fields", but it does allow me to PUT with the same format.

```
{
    "first_name": "Deepak",
    "last_name": "Bandi",
    "email": "bandideepakreddy@gmail.com",
    "company": "",
    "phone":"3123152269",
    "store_credit":"",
    "notes":"",
    "tax_exempt_category":"",
    "customer_group_id": 0,
    "form_fields": [
        {
           "name": "Rep Id",
           "value": "10025"
        }
   ]
}
```

I did see a similar question for Products here : [How can I update custom fields using the BigCommerce API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405477/how-can-i-update-custom-fields-using-the-bigcommerce-api)

But the same concept does not work on Customers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the API enables updating of form fields. Which is more than a little frustrating...

[image]

Comment: In their v3 API you can [update form fields](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/e24cecca97d81-upsert-customer-form-field-values) but cannot create them.